# Generate Google Maps URL to display custom map generated by v3 API in Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, layer, routeboxer

in my website I use Google Maps API v3 and Routeboxer to generate a map where the user can set a route and view Points of Interest around it, this is an example of output:

[image: Map generated with Javascript on my website]

Now I would also like to generate a URL so that I can view the same map (including the route and custom markers) on the Google Maps website.

Is this possible at all? I can only find URL schemes to view just the route or just 1 single marker, not a combination of the 2 (the markers are not waypoints, otherwise it would be easy).

It should be possible to create a custom layer on Google Maps to display this kind of information (I believe that's what the "My Maps" feature does), but I am not sure if you can pass all this information in 1 set of calls, especially from an external website as I cannot seem to find an API call that creates a "my map".

Answer (score 0):

Well while Google Maps itself doesn't make this feature available, you can still make a web page that does exactly this - encode marker and route information to generate an URL, while being able to decode it and show it in an embedded Google Maps widget ;-)

Note you will likely need a domain name, a web server etc... and that will, without a doubt, cost you time and money... But can be worth the investment depending on your use of the feature.